# aws put-target isn't adding any target to rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, aws-event-bridge

The goal is to deploy a Lambda and run it every 1 minute. I'm able to deploy but `put-targets` is not adding lambda as target on the rule? (Shows no targets in console).

```bash
    aws iam create-role --role-name lambda-basic-execution --assume-role-policy-document file://lambda-trust-policy.json    
    aws iam attach-role-policy --role-name lambda-basic-execution --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
    sleep 5
    aws lambda create-function --function-name "GlobalEntry" --handler globalentry --zip-file fileb://globalentry.zip \
    --region="us-east-1" \
    --environment '{"Variables":{"TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID":"${TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID}","TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN":"${TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN}"}}' \
    --role "arn:aws:iam::${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}:role/lambda-basic-execution" \
    --runtime go1.x
    aws events put-rule \
    --name GlobalEntryCron \
    --region="us-east-1" \
    --state 'ENABLED' \
    --schedule-expression 'rate(1 minute)'
    aws lambda add-permission \
    --region="us-east-1" \
    --function-name GlobalEntry \
    --statement-id GlobalEntryEvent \
    --action 'lambda:InvokeFunction' \
    --principal events.amazonaws.com \
    --source-arn arn:aws:events:us-east-1:${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}:rule/GlobalEntryCron
    aws events put-targets --rule GlobalEntryCron --targets \
    '{"Id":"1","Arn":"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}:function:GlobalEntry"}'
```

Comment: This [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/events/put-targets.html) uses a different format for the `--targets` value. That is, without single quote and with equal signs instead of colons. Have you tried this way? Besides, if you used single quotes in shell, it won't substitute ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID} with the variable value.

Comment: Yes I did try with equals sign as well and also hardcoding AWS Account Id and also tried using a targets.json file with hardcoded AWS account Id as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-run-lambda-schedule.html) .

Answer (score 0):

I missed specifying region to `put-targets`, solution:

```bash
    aws events put-targets --rule GlobalEntryCron --targets \
    --region="us-east-1" \
    '{"Id":"1","Arn":"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}:function:GlobalEntry"}'
```